# PendingIntent not working on notification

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, android-pendingintent

I am showing multiple notifications, each notification with its own id, so all notifications are properly shown. My problem is that when clicking on the last notification, the PendingIntent used is the first one instead of the last one. I don't understand why this is happening as I'm using the FLAG_ONE_SHOT. This is the piece of code:

```
final PendingIntent pendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your pending intent id. use different one in place of 0

Answer (score 1):

Use different `requestCode` of Pending Intent instead of "0".

> final PendingIntent pendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(your_id,
>   PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

Answer (score 0):

if you want to maintain all the notifications with unique id then this might help you.

```
private PendingIntent getContentIntent(String key, Context context, int currentTimeStamp) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setComponent(getComponentName(context));
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    return PendingIntent.getActivity(context, currentTimeStamp, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
}
```

this method will return you pending intent object